# Retrieve varchar autogenerated primary key through triggers using JDBCTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am using MySQL Database and Spring JdbcTemplates to access the DB. I have a table called logs which has the following fields:-

```
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '11111111111111111',
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modification_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

I have a trigger on top of it:-

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_logs_insert BEFORE INSERT ON logs
 FOR EACH ROW
 SET NEW.creation_time = UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.modification_time = UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NEW.id = (SELECT UUID());
```

I want the Spring jdbcTemplate code which retrieves the Id generated by the Trigger on the insert of a record.

I tried KeyHolder(GeneratedKeyHolder) but that is meant for numbers. 
I want a code that can instantaneously retrieve the id.

Comment: You want what to happen?

Comment: @Drew, I want to retrieve the id that is generated. I have created a Log record with all the fields except the fields generated by trigger. How can I retrieve the Id which is automatically generated by Trigger. The Id generated is uuid and so not a number. How can I get the primary key of the record that was generated by trigger inside my java code using spring jdbc template.